# Are multiple matches possible with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

http://regex101.com/r/wU1lP3

```
([*][^*]+[*])+
```

I want this to match all of the `*hi*`s but it only matches the first one.

Also, how would multiple matches work with the javascript match command?

```
var match = $('textarea').val().match(<regex that matches multiple patterns>);
```

Would it return an array? If not, how could I get it to return an array?

Comment: you might find the visibone regex cheat-sheet useful if you have any similar problems
http://www.visibone.com/regular-expressions/
i'm not affiliated, it's just one i found & use ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Add the [global modifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) after the delimiters: `//g`.

```
var match = $('textarea').val().match(/[*][^*]+[*]/g);
```

Your updated [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/nG5gI3).

Comment: Yes but you need to remove the `+` quantifier at the end to obtain separated results.

Answer (score 2):

Use [the g flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags) :

```
var matches = $('textarea').val().match(/([*][^*]+[*])+/g);
```

Comment: Haha, I think this is the closest to a tie I've had in a while; take my +1